# Cannot navigate to a specific screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created two files, "Browse.js" and "Drawer.js". I have some buttons in "Browse.js", but when I wrap up my complete "Browse.js" in "Drawer.js"
like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TextInput, View } from "react-native";
import Slider from "react-native-slider";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Foundation } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { RoleLogin } from "./Browse";
import Browse from "./Browse";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"; 
import Login from "./Login"

import { Divider, Button, Block, Text, Switch } from "../components";
import { theme, mocks } from "../constants";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (

 <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Browse" openByDefault>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Browse" component={Browse} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I cannot navigate to a specific screen from Drawer screen. Instead, I get this error:

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload was not handled by any navigator.

Here Is My Browse.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { ThemeColors } from "react-navigation";
import { Card, Badge, Button, Block, Text } from "../components";
import { theme, mocks } from "../constants";
import Settings from "./Settings";
import { NotificationsScreen, App } from "./Settings";
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Drawer1 from "./Settings";
import Home from "./Settings";

class Browse extends Component {
  state = {
    // active: "Products",
    // active: "Select_Acivity",
    categories: [],
    error: [],
    // data: [],
    roles: "",
    username: "",
    password: "",
    lading: false,
    title: "",
    data: "",
  };

  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Drawer fun start++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Drawer fun close++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

  //*******************navagte to setting when data fetch start*************************/

  RoleLogin() {
    //  const { data } = this.state;
    // const { username, password, roles } = this.state;
    fetch(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
      //fetch(
      // "https://nasdigital.tech/Android_API_CI/validate_login_details",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        // body: JSON.stringify([{ data}]),
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((json) => {
        //login to check details from server and then display or navigate to another screen
        if (json != "error") {
          // if (response && response.length && response[0].message != "error")
          alert(JSON.stringify(json));
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Drawer", {
            data: json.title,
          });
          // .navigate("Settings", { data: json.title });
          // this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings",{data : json.title});
        } else {
          alert("Cehck Details");
        }
      })

      .catch((error) => alert("Cehck Details"));
  }
  //*******************navagte to setting when data fetch close**************************** */

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ categories: this.props.categories });
  }

  // handleTab = tab => {
  //   const { categories } = this.props;
  //   const filtered = categories.filter(category =>
  //     category.tags.includes(tab.toLowerCase())
  //   );

  //   this.setState({ active: tab, categories: filtered });
  // };

  renderTab(tab) {
    const { active } = this.state;
    const isActive = active === tab;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={`tab-${tab}`}
        onPress={() => this.handleTab(tab)}
        style={[styles.tab, isActive ? styles.active : null]}
      >
        <Text size={16} medium gray={!isActive} secondary={isActive}>
          {tab}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { profile, navigation } = this.props;
    const { categories } = this.state;
    // // const tabs = ["Products", "Inspirations", "Shop"];
    // const tabs = ["Select_Activity", "Market_Visit"];
    // const tabs = ["Select_Activity"];
    const tabs = [""];
    return (
      <Block>
        <Block flex={false} row center space="between" style={styles.header}>
          <Text h1 bold>
            Select Activity
          </Text>
          <Button onPress={() => this.RoleLogin()}>
            <Image source={profile.avatar} style={styles.avatar} />
          </Button>
          {/* <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Settings")}>
            <Image source={profile.avatar} style={styles.avatar} />
          </Button> */}
        </Block>

        <Block flex={false} row style={styles.tabs}>
          {tabs.map((tab) => this.renderTab(tab))}
        </Block>

        <ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          style={{ paddingVertical: theme.sizes.base * 2 }}
        >
          <Block flex={false} row space="between" style={styles.categories}>
            {categories.map((category) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                key={category.name}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("MarketVisit", { category })}
              >
                <Card center middle shadow style={styles.category}>
                  <Badge
                    margin={[0, 0, 15]}
                    size={90}
                    color="rgb(255, 163, 102)"
                  >
                    <Image source={category.image} />
                  </Badge>
                  <Text medium height={20}>
                    {category.name}
                  </Text>
                  <Text gray caption>
                    {category.count}
                  </Text>
                </Card>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
          </Block>
        </ScrollView>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Browse.defaultProps = {
  profile: mocks.profile,
  categories: mocks.categories,
};

export default Browse;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2,
  },
  avatar: {
    height: theme.sizes.base * 1.0,
    width: theme.sizes.base * 1.5,
  },
  tabs: {
    borderBottomColor: theme.colors.gray2,
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    marginVertical: theme.sizes.base,
    marginHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 2,
  },
  tab: {
    marginRight: theme.sizes.base * 7,
    paddingBottom: theme.sizes.base,
  },
  active: {
    borderBottomColor: theme.colors.secondary,
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
  },
  categories: {
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    paddingHorizontal: theme.sizes.base * 1.5,
    marginBottom: theme.sizes.base * 2,
  },
  category: {
    // this should be dynamic based on screen width
    minWidth: (width - theme.sizes.padding * 2.4 - theme.sizes.base) / 2,
    maxWidth: (width - theme.sizes.padding * 2.4 - theme.sizes.base) / 2,
    maxHeight: (width - theme.sizes.padding * 2.4 - theme.sizes.base) / 2,
  },
});
```

and here is my navigation file:

```
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import Welcome from "../screens/Welcome";
import Login from "../screens/Login";
import SignUp from "../screens/SignUp";
import Forgot from "../screens/Forgot";
import Explore from "../screens/Explore";
// import Explore1 from "../screens/Explore1";
// import Explore2 from "../screens/Explore2";
// import Explore3 from "../screens/Explore3";
// import Explore4 from "../screens/Explore4";
// import Explore5 from "../screens/Explore5";
// import Explore6 from "../screens/Explore6";
// import Explore7 from "../screens/Explore7";
// import Explore8 from "../screens/Explore8";
import Browse from "../screens/Browse";
import Product from "../screens/Product";
//import Settings from "../screens/Settings";
import Drawer from "../screens/Drawer";
import MarketVisit from "../screens/MarketVisit";

import { theme } from "../constants";

const screens = createStackNavigator(
  {

    Welcome,
    Login,
    SignUp,
    Forgot,
    Explore,
    Drawer,
    //Browse,
    //Product,
    //Settings,
    MarketVisit,   
    // NotificationsScreen,
    // App,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        height: theme.sizes.base * 4,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.white, // or 'white
        borderBottomColor: "transparent",
        elevation: 0 // for android
      },
      // headerBackImage: <Image source={require("../assets/2.jpg")} />,
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerLeftContainerStyle: {
        alignItems: "center",
        marginLeft: theme.sizes.base * 2,
        paddingRight: theme.sizes.base
      },
      headerRightContainerStyle: {
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingRight: theme.sizes.base
      }
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(screens);
```

Comment: At first, stack navigator is bad imported. Also use of `createStackNavigator` is wrong. Looks like you are mixing navigation v4 and v5. Check how it should be done from the very first step, install stack navigator. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Comment: ok Please Bookmark My question. if I have any query further I will comment here.

Comment: Also `createAppContainer` is also not used in v5. Check this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#navigation-container .You have to change whole Navigation structure.

Comment: BY changing Navigation TO V5. do I need to change my whole code

Comment: `@react-navigation/drawer` and `@react-navigation/native` is actually from v5. Or maybe you are using compatibility layer, but i recommend to switch it to v5 since you do not have  lot of code yet. That refactor may take some time, but not so long and you will better understand what is going on with React navigation