# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"MarketVisit","params":{"category"}} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. please help.

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"MarketVisit","params":{"category":{"id":"market_visit","name":"Market Visit","tags":["Select_Activity"],"image":3}}} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'MarketVisit'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.
```

Comment: Do you want to navigate in the same stack or in to different stack?

Answer (score 0):

Check exactly what that error said.

> Do you have a screen named 'MarketVisit'?

Go to your navigation root, where `MarketVisit` screen is declared and check, if name of that screen is the same as name, where you want to navigate

Comment: Yes, Exactly same.  This error shows when I wrap my Browse.js file In Drawer.Navigator Otherwise work fine. so please tell me whats the solution on that

Comment: How your Browse.js file looks like?

Comment: please check this link => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627777/not-navigating-to-specific-screen-in-react-native